# Access struct in struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am working on a tree algorithm. These are the structures in my program:

```
typedef struct{
    double m;   
    double x[DIM];
    double v[DIM];
} Particle;

typedef struct{
    double lower[DIM];
    double upper[DIM];
} Box;

typedef struct Node{
    Particle p;
    Box box;
    struct Node *son[4];
} Node;
```

Now I have written a function myFunctA() which is given by:

```
void myFunctA(Particle *p, Node *t){
    int b=soNum(&t->box, &t->son->box, p); // Why does "&t->son->box" not work?
// do stuff ...
}
```

Within function myFunctA() I want to pass the `box` of `t` and the `box` of the `son` of `t` to the function `soNum()`. `soNum()` is given by

```
int soNum(Box *box, Box *sonbox, Particle *p){
// do stuff ...
}
```

I am trying to do this by using `&t->son->box` which does not work. I also tried `(&t->son)->box`. The error I get is always:

```
error: request for member ‘box’ in something not a structure or union
     int b=soNum(&t->box, &t->son->box, p);
```

I think this is easy, but I am still quite new to C and find it somehow difficult to see it. I hope someone can help me!

Comment: `t->son->box ` should be something like `t->son[INDEX]->box`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operator `->` applies to a pointer, not to a `struct`. `t` is a pointer so `t->son` is correct. However, `son` is *not* a pointer, it is an array of pointers. Therefore

```
t->son->box
```

needs to be

```
t->son[someIndex]->box
```

where `someIndex` is an expression evaluating to an `int` between zero and three, inclusive.

Answer (score 2):

`t->son->box` needs to be something like `t->son[INDEX]->box` (son is an array of node pointers).

This compiles:

```
#define DIM 3
typedef struct{
    double m;   
    double x[DIM];
    double v[DIM];
} Particle;

typedef struct{
    double lower[DIM];
    double upper[DIM];
} Box;

typedef struct Node{
    Particle p;
    Box box;
    struct Node *son[4];
} Node;

int soNum(Box *box, Box *sonbox, Particle *p){
// do stuff ...
    return 0;
}
void myFunctA(Particle *p, Node *t){
    int b=soNum(&t->box, &t->son[0]->box, p); // Why does "&t->son->box" not work?
// do stuff ...
}
```